# How to check Api is triggered or not and how to abort the api if its triggered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, api, ecmascript-2016

I am creating a search page, to search for some data on keyup, for each keyup a API being called, but I want to stop the previous call if 2nd API being called.

```
myFunction(term) {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    const signal = controller.signal;
    controller.abort();
    var apiUrl = window.BASE_URL + '/search?param=' + term;
    console.log(apiUrl);
    this.setState({
      searching: true
    });
    return fetch(apiUrl, { credentials: 'include', signal: signal })
      .then(this.handleErrors)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
         console.log(responseJson);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example to cancel previous fetch requests:

```
const controller = useRef<AbortController>() // useRef: for function component. 
// You can create a property in a class component to store this 
// (e.g. `this.controller = null` in your constructor)  

function fetchAndAbortPrevious() {
  controller.current?.abort()
  controller.current = new AbortController()
  fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts', {
    signal: controller.current.signal,
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((response) => console.log(response))
    .catch((err) => console.log('error: ', err))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already providing the `signal` to the `fetch` call, but since you initialised it inside your function scope, the outer world has no reference to it, so it can't be used.

So f.ex. pass it as a param to your function:

```
const controller = new AbortController();
const signal = controller.signal;

myFunction(term, signal) { ... }
```

Then whenever needed call abort:

`signal.abort()`

Also be sure you are not using IE as it is [not supported on that browser.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController#browser_compatibility)

---

Other option to store signal object outside and reinitialise it when `myFunction` is called:

```
signal;

myFunction(term) {
  this.signal ? signal.abort() : false;

  const controller = new AbortController();
  this.signal = controller.signal;

  < ... >
}
```

Comment: Can I use singnal.abort() inside myFunction()?

Comment: Edited with another way